# How to get a value from a table that appear in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query where it goes to one table gets a value, in this case its `TeamCode` and then takes it and finds the `TeamCode` in another table columns named `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` and return the `Team` column from the club table.

```
SELECT  Team
FROM    club
WHERE   TeamCode IN (SELECT DISTINCT    
HomeTeam and Awayteam FROM matches);
```

This code for some reason only returns one entry when it should be more than 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That actually works? Try this:

```
SELECT  Team
FROM    club
WHERE   TeamCode IN (SELECT DISTINCT HomeTeam FROM Matches
                     UNION 
                     SELECT DISTINCT AwayTeam FROM Matches);
```

Or exists:

```
SELECT t.team
FROM club t
WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from Matches s
             where s.awayTeam = t.team 
                or s.HomeTeam = t.Team)
```

Or with an inner join:

```
SELECT t.team
FROM club t
INNER JOIN Matches s
 ON(s.awayTeam = t.team 
    or s.HomeTeam = t.Team)
```